# Changin Columns in glossaries-extra and style=long3colheader

Tags: header-footer, glossaries, columns

I'm searching the web and can't find a solution.

I'm writing a text with many shortcuts. I found a way, to print a glossary (type=acronym) using the style "long3colheader" ... an everything works fine.

But ...

[image]

As you can see, i have to write the longform in the description.

I changed the style in "long4colheader", believing, that i get a 4th column, that gives me the abbility to place the longform there.

The entry /newglosseryentry has the parameter "long" (via description) so i thought, that i can display its content in the acronym-glossary.

But i can't.

I read the package-description, but i can't find the correct name for the long form, neither a way, to display it in the glossary.

```
    \newglossaryentry{BSt}
{
        type=\acronymtype,
        name={BSt},
        description={\textbf{\textit{(Bildungsstätte)}}  Austragungsort für Seminare der ....., teilweise 
        mit integriertem, eigenen, Hotelbetrieb.}
}
```

The Code to print the print the glossary is:

```
% ---------------------------------------------
% - Änderung des Headers und Erzeugen des Abkürzungsverzeichnisses
% - Fomatierung des Eintrages in kursiv
% ---------------------------------------------

\renewcommand*\entryname{Abk.} % Änderung des Namens der 1. Spalte 
\renewcommand*\descriptionname{Bedeutung} % Änderung des Namens der 2. Spalte 
\renewcommand*\pagelistname{Seite\\} % Änderung des Namens der 3. Spalte 
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossdescfont}{emph} % Formatierung der Spalte 'Bedeutung' in kursiv in beiden Verzeichnissen.

\printglossary[style=long3colheader, type=\acronymtype,title={Abkürzungen}] % Erstellen des Abkürzungsverzeichnisses  3 Spalten und Änderung des Titels.


%% ---------------------------------------------
\newpage % \newpage just to demonstrate that links are correct
%% ---------------------------------------------
%
% ---------------------------------------------
% - Änderung des Headers und Erzeugen des Glossars
% ---------------------------------------------

\renewcommand*\entryname{Begriff} % Änderung des Namens der 1. Spalte 
\renewcommand*\descriptionname{Bedeutung} % Änderung des Namens der 2. Spalte 
\renewcommand*\pagelistname{Seite\\} % Änderung des Namens der 3. Spalte 
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}} % Einträge der ersten Spalte werden fett

\printglossary[style=long3colheader, type=main, title={Glossar}] % Erstellen des Glossars mit 3 Spalten und Änderung des Titels.
% ---------------------------------------------
```

Any suggestions?

Regards

Stefan